# Proof clarification for Question 68 of Spivak's 'Calculus' - exploring the function $f(x)=\alpha x + x^2 \sin(1/x)$ for $\alpha =1$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Question 68 from Chapter 11 of Spivak's *Calculus* is about interrogating the behavior of the function $f$ defined by: $f(x)=\alpha x + x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, for $\alpha$ values $\geq 1$.

I am having some difficulty following Spivak's logic in the solution manual.

To provide some relevant background:

1. $f'(x)=\alpha +2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$
2. Spivak creates the function $g$ defined as $g(y)=2(\sin y)/y-\cos(y)$...where $h(x)=y=\frac{1}{x}$
3. For any $y_0$ where $g'(y_0)=0$, we have that $$|g(y_0)|=\frac{2+y_0^2}{\sqrt{4+y_0^4}}\gt 1$$

Here is the question of interest:

> Show that if $\alpha=1$, then $f$ is not [strictly] increasing in any interval around $0$.

Here is Spivak's solution manual's entry:

> We have $f'(x)=1+g(1/x)$. Now we clearly have $g(y) \lt 0$ for arbitrarily large $y$ (since $g(y)$ is practically $-\cos y$ for large $y$), so for arbitrarily large $y$ we have \begin{align}g(y) \lt - \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}\lt -1 \end{align}Thus $f'(x) \lt 0$ for arbitrarily small $x$, while we also have $f'(x) \gt 0$ for arbitrarily small $x$.

---

Starting with the problem statement, it seems to me that our goal should be to show that for any arbitrary $\delta \gt 0$, there is an $x \in (0,\delta)$ such that $f'(x) \lt 0$. If we do that, then we can be sure that $f$ is not strictly increasing in any neighborhood around $0$.

Given this, I really do not understand what Spivak's argument is saying. Framing this from the perspective of $y$, it seems to me the Spivak's argument is saying that for any $N \gt N_0$ (where $N_0$ denotes the 'sufficiently far away' condition), we can always find a $y \gt N$ satisfying the statement:

$$g(y) \lt - \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}\lt -1 $$

It is not clear to me why we are in a position to assert this. Spivak is presumably making use of the statement: For any $y_0$ where $g'(y_0)=0$, we have that $$|g(y_0)|=\frac{2+y_0^2}{\sqrt{4+y_0^4}}\gt 1$$

but I cannot see how. Why should it be the case that for any sufficiently far away $N$, I can find an instance of a $y_0 \gt N$ satisfying $g'(y_0)=0$? Further, even if this *is* true, we only know that $|g(y_0)| \gt 1$. Why could it not be the case that for all such instances of $y_0$, we have that $g(y_0) \gt 1$?

I suspect it becomes relevant to show that these $y_0$'s are local minimum/maximum, rather than merely inflection points...but I am not certain at which point this was done by Spivak.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 1):

**NOT AN ANSWER**

I read your approach and it seems to me that it is correct, though I myself don't know if that is what the author had in mind.

I would rather follow this path. When $\alpha =1$, we have, for $x \neq 0$,
$$f'(x) = 1+2x \sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac1{x}\right),$$
and
$$f''(x) = 2\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right) - \frac2{x}\cos\left(\frac1{x}\right) -\frac1{x^2}\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right).$$
To show, for example, that $f(x)$ is not increasing in any right neighborhood of $0$, notice that for any $k=1,2,\dots$
$$f'\left(\frac1{2k\pi}\right)=0,$$
and
$$f''\left(\frac1{2k\pi}\right)=-4k\pi.$$
so that $\frac1{2\pi k}$ is a local maximum. This answers part (c) of the question.

When $\alpha >1$ note that, for $0< x < \frac{\alpha-1}2$,
$$f'(x) = \alpha + 2x \sin\left(\frac1{x}\right) -\cos \left(\frac1{x}\right) \geq \alpha -2x -1>0$$
which answers to question (d), i.e. for $\alpha >1$ there is a neighborhood of $0$ in which the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: Could you please clarify why showing that $f(\frac{1}{2 \pi k})=\frac{1}{2 \pi k}$ is a local maximum proves that $f$ is not increasing in any interval to the right of $0$? Looking at when $k=1$, $k=2$, and $k=3$, note that $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \gt \frac{1}{4 \pi} \gt \frac{1}{6 \pi}$. This suggests that as we move closer to $0$, the local maximum are getting smaller.

Comment: Is the idea, then, that there is no way to connect, from the left to right, $\frac{1}{6 \pi k}$ to $\frac{1}{4 \pi k}$ to $\frac{1}{2 \pi k}$ in a strictly increasing fashion **given** that each point is a local maximum (and therefore there must be an interval to the right of each point that contains either a constant section or a strictly decreasing section...which violates the features of strictly increasing intervals)?

Comment: @S.Cramer Call $x_k = \frac1{2k\pi}$, we have that $$f'(x_k) = 0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to x_k^+} \frac{f'(x)}{x-x_k} =f''(x_k)< 0.$$
Hence there is right neighborhood of $x_k$ in which $f'(x) < 0$. Does this clarify?

Comment: Perfect. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain if this is what Spivak had in mind with his proof, but the following *extra* information seems to validate Spivak's general approach.

We need to answer the following question:

> Why could it not be the case that for all such instances of $y_0$, we have that $g(y_0) \gt 1$?

---

We will show that for any $N$, we can find a $y_m$ satisfying $y_m \gt N$, and $g(y_m)\lt -1$

From the prompt, we know that for any $y_0$ where $g'(y_0)=0$, we have $$|g(y_0)|=\frac{2+y_0^2}{\sqrt{4+y_0^4}}\gt 1 \quad (\dagger_1)$$

Consider Spivak's function $g(y)=2(\sin y)/y-\cos(y)$. Note that $g$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R \ (*)$. Therefore, on any closed interval $[a,b]$, we have a minimum $y_m$.

Consider an arbitrary $N$. Next, we will show that there is a $y^* \gt N$ such that $g(y^*) = -1$. To see this, consider when $y^*=2\pi n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ where $n \gt \frac{N}{2\pi}$.

Now, consider the interval $[N+\frac{y^*}{2},y^*+1]$. Suppose that $y^*$ is the minimum point for this interval; importantly, note that $y^*$ is clearly not an end point. By $(*)$ this means that $g'(y^*)=0$. However, by $(\dagger_1)$, we should have that $g(y^*) \gt 1$ or $g(y^*) \lt -1$. But we showed that $g(y^*)=-1$. Clearly, then, $y^*$ is not the minimum point of the interval $[N+\frac{y^*}{2},y^*+1]$. But if $y^*$ is the not the minimum point, then there must be a $y_m \in [N+\frac{y^*}{2},y^*+1]$ such that $g(y_m) \lt g(y^*)$ . This would imply that $y_m \gt N$ and $g(y_m) \lt -1$. This approach works for any $N$ so we can generalize $(\dagger_2)$.

---

Next, note the relationship between $g$ and the function $h(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$. In particular, we have $g(\frac{1}{x})=h(x)$. Moreover, we have that $f'(x)=1+h(x)$...or, equivalently, $f'(x)=1+g(\frac{1}{x})$. Using $(\dagger_2)$, we will show that for any $\delta \gt 0$, there is an $x \in (0,\delta)$ such that $f'(x) \lt 0$.

Consider some arbitrary $\delta \gt 0$. We are interested in an $0\lt x \lt \delta$. It is useful to frame this as $\frac{1}{x} \gt \frac{1}{\delta}$. Applying $(\dagger_2)$, let $N=\frac{1}{\delta} \gt 0$. Then we know that there is a $y_m \gt \frac{1}{\delta}$ such that $g(y_m) \lt -1$. Let $y_m=\frac{1}{x}$...rearranging, we have that $x=\frac{1}{y_m}$.

Therefore, we can conclude that $f'(\frac{1}{y_m})=1+g(y_m) \lt 0$. Noting that $\frac{1}{y_m} \gt 0$ and $y_m \gt \frac{1}{\delta}$, we have that $0\lt \frac{1}{y_m} \lt \delta$. This argument works for any $\delta$. $\quad \square$